# Show datetime dialog in SWT in 24 Hour format

Tags: java, swt

I want to show DateTime dialog in SWT in 24 hour format, Please let me know how to do that?

Comment: @Gaurav Have a look at this widget instead: [CDateTime](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/cdatetime/cdatetime.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The presentation seems to depend on OS settings. See [Eclipse Bug 337468](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=337468) for a discussion.

Changing the settings for the time representation in your OS should also change the appearance used by the DateTime widget.

Comment: I am making an application I want to distribute to customers. I don't want tto tell them they have to change OS settings!!

Comment: @whomaniac Then don't use the SWT DateTime dialog. As an alternative, Baz suggested the [CDateTime](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/cdatetime/cdatetime.php) widget in his comment to the question.